# Static Search Results using Tapir

Tags: jquery, full-text-search, jekyll, static-site

Very much new to web development and Jekyll, and trying to implement [TapirGo](http://tapirgo.com) into my website to allow for static search. It appears as though their Jquery plugin is active on my site (when manually adding the parameter ?query=example to my site, it seems to make mention of tapir when loading my website) but I cannot figure out for the life of me how to actually get results to appear in anything meaningful.

Ideally, I'd have a form in my website that would display a list of results and allow the visitor to click on one.

Anyways, here's my (mostly copy and pasted) code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/respond.min.js"></script>   
<script src="/js/jquery-tapir.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#search_results').tapir({'token': '502f16a53f61b006d6000bbc'});
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div id="search_results"></div>
</body>
```

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Comment: very interesting, I will have a look and implement that on my website. I'll come back to you after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display result you need to create an input text and a button. You don't need to call `tapir(...)` method because the way they implement it is crap :) (or I don't like it, choose which one you prefer)

So first do the text box and the button, followed by the `div` that will display result.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" name="query" />
<input type="button" name="search" value="search" />
<div id="results"></div>

 ...
```

and then,

```
// Javascript
$('input[name="search"]').click(function(e) {
    $.getJSON(
        'http://tapirgo.com/api/1/search.json?token=' 
             + 'PUT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE' 
             + '&query=' 
             + $('input[name="query"]').val()
             + '&callback=?', 
        function(data) {
            $('#results').empty();
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $('#results').append('<div class="result"><h3><a href="'
                                     + val.link + '">' 
                                     + val.title + '</a></h3><p>' 
                                     + val.summary + '</p></div>');
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Hello, I forked the original project: https://github.com/sp4ce/jquery-plugin/ to include the 'query' option that allow you to do what I describe here

Answer (score 0):

I think Tapir is no longer supported. I have implemented a static search mechanism [myself](http://pradeepnayak.in/search.html) using Jquery. You can reuse the code from [here](https://github.com/pradeep1288/pradeep1288.github.com/blob/master/search.html)